# parse push notification text is displayed truncated on android device

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I use Parse Dashboard to send push notification to android devices.
I am sending the following message "Good morning , the sun is shining , and i can not see this fully"
The push icon appears on my android device on the screen top left as expected. when i swipe it down i see it displayed as :
"Good morning , the sun is shining ..."
the other part of the text is truncated.

what can be done so that all the push text will be displayed when the user swipe down the push icon?

see attached[image]

Nathan

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating your notification, add the following code

`.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Your text goes here..."))`